# Como no permitir que un usuario se inscriba a un mismo dictado

Tags: laravel-8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas tardes estoy usando fakers para llenar mi base de datos.
El temas es que me inscribe el mismo usuario a un dictado. Y lo que deberia suceder es que se inscriba a dictados distintos.[image: no deberia tener por cada dictation_id el un user_id igual]

en mi tabla de creacion de inscripciones puse que sea clave unica

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unique();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

como deberia llamar a mi faker ?

Comment: este seria mi factory 'user_id' => User::all()->random()->id,

Comment: ahora que lo decis estoy pensando que mi dictation_id deberia ser unico.

Comment: adjunte la foto de mi base de datos asi tengo armada las relaciones. En un dictado puedo tener a muchos usuarios, pero un usuario no puede estar inscripto en el mismo dictado 2 veces

Comment: si en realidad tenia duda sobre mi base de datos pero considerando lo que me decis deberia quedar asi (ver imagen del post)